# Convert two arrays to an array of arrays compatible with the result of `findContours`

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I need to convert two arrays to an array of arrays compatible with the result of `findContours` as the following example shows:

```
a = [1,3,5,7]
b = [2,4,6,8]
c = convert(a, b)
print(c)
# c = [ [[1,2]], [[3,4]], [[5,6]], [[7,8]] ]
```

How can I do it using NumPy?

Comment: `a` and `b` are not arrays, and why would you *want* an array of arrays if you were to use `numpy`? Rather, you'd almost certainly want a two dimensional array

Comment: `np.column_stack((a, b))[:, None]`

Comment: Can you provide some more context for this, explain what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With zip an list comprehension it's quite easy to achieve what you want.

```
a = [1,3,5,7]
b = [2,4,6,8]

c = list([[x,y]] for x,y in zip(a,b))

print(c)
```

## Output

```
[[[1, 2]], [[3, 4]], [[5, 6]], [[7, 8]]]
```

In case you need a numpy array:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,3,5,7])
b = np.array([2,4,6,8])

c = np.array(list([[x,y]] for x,y in zip(a,b)))

print(c.shape)
```

## Output:

```
(4, 1, 2)
```

I don't really know what `findContours` is though.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [**`np.dstack(..)`** [numpy-doc]](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html) here, and then [**`.reshape(..)`** [numpy-doc]](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) the result:

```
>>> np.dstack((a,b)).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
array([[[1, 2]],

       [[3, 4]],

       [[5, 6]],

       [[7, 8]]])
```